# Using the Stopwatch with Async methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have some code as follows:

```
public void Start()
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod1);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod2);

    watch.Stop();
    Log(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod3);
}
```

Because MyMethod1 and MyMethod2 are called Asynchronously watch.Stop() gets called at the wrong time. How I can ensure that .Stop gets called and logged after MyMethod1 and MyMethod2 finish BUT ensure that MyMethod3 does not have to wait.

I want to keep all Stopwatch functionality in my Start() method and not have the logging in any of my 3 methods i.e. MyMethod1, MyMethod2 and MyMethod3

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` method.

```cs
watch.Start();
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod1);
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod2);
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new [] {t1, t2}, tasks => watch.Stop());
```

If you're targeting for .NET 4.5 and upper, you can also use the method `Task.WhenAll`. It returns a task that will complete when all of the passed Task objects have completed.

```cs
Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ContinueWith(t => watch.Stop());
```

Answer (score -1):

You need create a new Thread that will handle the logging issue.
This logging thread will wait on `EventWaitHandle.WaitAll(threadsEventWaitHandles)` that will contain all the threads EventWaitHandles.
Something like that :

```
private void LoggingThread()
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    EventWaitHandle.WaitAll(threadsEventWaitHandles);

    watch.Stop();
    Log(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

And also the methods `MyMethod1, MyMethod2` will signal to the loging thread whene they finish.
Something like that :

```
private void MyMethod1()
{
    //... your code
    EventWaitHandle.Set();
}

private void MyMethod2()
{
    //... your code
    EventWaitHandle.Set();
}
```

So you can ensure that MyMethod3 does not have to wait.

Comment: `ContinueWhenAll()` is much simpler and also more efficient.

Comment: @svick, You're right, I did not know this technique. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
    public void Start()
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod1);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod2);

        Task.WaitAll(); // Wait for previous tasks to finish

        watch.Stop();
        Log(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod3);
    }
```

Comment: "...BUT ensure that MyMethod3 does not have to wait."

Comment: +1, a very simple solution. I was thinking along the lines of `ContinueWith`.