# measure execution time using interceptors

Tags: c#, aop, interceptor, castle

I am intercepting wcf calls of services I host in my application in order to display data about the service (how many calls each method handled, log the methods parameters etc`). In addition to that, I want to measure the execution time of each method.

I am already wrapping the instance with Castle interceptor, and I use `StopWatch` to measure the sync methods.

However, I can not use stopwatch on async method because I have 2 different methods (for `beginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`, I intercept the WCF invoker).

How can I measure the execution time, or at least relate the invocations of Begin and End?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like this question was already answered here [Using the Stopwatch with Async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381426/using-the-stopwatch-with-async-methods)

Cheers

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear so I improved my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

I realized that the `invocation.ReturnValue` holds the task so all I had to do is Implementing a `TaskInterceptor` :

```
public class TaskInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var task = invocation.ReturnValue as Task;

        InterceptBeforeInvoking();

        invocation.Proceed();

        task.ContinueWith(InterceptAfterInvocation);


    }

    private void InterceptAfterInvocation(Task obj)
    {


    }

    private void InterceptBeforeInvoking()
    {


    }
}
```